# How to make ascending text is CS5 PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text, cs5

I want to be able to get a ascending/descending size ( 3D ) effect with CS5 Photoshop text. Like this.

I've tried make each letter a different size and `edit -> transform -> scale` and am very limited.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't directly reference CS5. I no longer have it available to work in. However...

You can't do this easily with Live Type.

But you can create a smart object of the type (or rasterize the type) then transform. Converting type to a shape layer would also allow the transformation to work. Really, using a smart object with live type may be best because you can edit the content of the text later if needed.

Just highlight the layer and choose `Edit > Free Transform`

Hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> keys (Mac) or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> keys (Win) and click a handle and drag it...

[image]

I created a smart object of a standard type layer so that the free transform was possible.

- Command/Ctrl key = Distort
- Option/Alt key = From Center
- Shift key = Constrain to 90° dragging

In newer versions of Photoshop, you can also utilize the `Perspective Warp` feature in the `Edit` menu.

Comment: Cs 3 introduced Smart objects.

Answer (score 0):

[This was the easiest solution.](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photoshop-text/text-effects/photoshop-simple-3d-type/) Up to step 8.

Essentially you convert the text to a shape -> transform path -> pull bottom right anchor down ( or left depending which side you want warped )

Comment: Please include the relevant content from the link in your answer itself. Otherwise your answer could be deleted

Comment: @ZachSaucier see edits